# Number of Automorphisms of $\Bbb Z/p \Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Since an automorphism of $\Bbb Z/p \Bbb Z, p$ prime, should map a generator of $\Bbb Z/p \Bbb Z$ to a generator of $\Bbb Z/p \Bbb Z$ it's enough to know how many generators does $\Bbb Z/p \Bbb Z$ have in order to calculate the number of automorphisms of $\Bbb Z/p \Bbb Z.$ Since $p$ is prime, this number should be $p-1.$

In the Algebra book (Lang) I was just reading that $\Bbb Z/p \Bbb Z$ has no automorphisms other than identity.

Can somebody explain what I missed here? Thanks.

Comment: Group or ring? ${}$

Answer (score 6):

As a group, $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ has $p-1$ automorphisms.

As a ring, $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ has $1$ automorphism.

Comment: Many thanks. It was not mentioned if it were about a group or ring. I then guess it was meant a ring. Can you explain the result in the case of a ring ? Does the principle remain the same: a generator is mapped to a generator ? How one would determine the generators of $Z/pZ$ considered as a ring ?

Comment: @user249018 When considering it as a ring, a homomorphism must map the identity to the identity. From there it follows that you only have one automorphism.

Answer (score 2):

The *empty set* is a minimal generating set for the ring $\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}$.

(note that I assume the convention that a multiplicative unit is part of the structure of a ring)

---

The flaw in the argument you use is that, while its true any automorphism of an algebraic structure will send a generating set to a generating set, it is *not* true in general that any correspondence between two generating sets will extend to an automorphism.

So while, say, $\{ 1 \}$ and $\{ 2 \}$ are both generating sets for $\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}$ (although they are not minimal generating sets), it is not guaranteed that there exists an automorphism sending $1 \mapsto 2$. (in fact, such an automorphism does not exist!)

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain how to get the generators of the ring $\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z} $ without trying for each element ? It is clear that the order of such an element must be $p-1\, $mod $p.$  At the other hand, understanding very well your point, can you give me a hint how to prove the statement that the set of automorphisms of the ring  $\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}$ has only one element, which is the identity ?

Comment: @user249018: The set $\{ 0 \}$ is also a generating set for the ring $\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}$. The problem, I think, is that you are stuck in the mindset of studying groups -- and more specifically thinking about *cyclic* groups. Rings are a different algebraic structure with more operations and more constants. Every ring automorphism is an automorphism of the underlying additive group (and also of the underlying multiplicative monoid), but not vice versa.

Comment: @user249018: Have you yet understood the fact that the *empty set* generates the ring $\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}$? I imagine you could clear up most of your confusion by working through that fact. (The analogous fact for groups is that the empty set generates the zero group. It turns out ring theory is a bit more interesting in this specific regard)

Comment: I dont understand that the empty sets generates the ring $\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z} $ . Can you elaborate on that ? Also, by writing $\{ 0 \}$ you probably mean the empty set, dont you ?